# How to avoid some flakky test fails in espresso android Testing?

Tags: android, android-espresso, ui-automation

In my test suite, out of 10, atleast 2 test failing every time but on running that method alone is not failing.how to handle this type of issue

As of now , I am doing with Thread.sleep to avoid more failures. How to do explicit wait

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: @mentallurg If I run a particular method alone, it's running perfect.On running a whole suite only making some methods fail.Even the failed method in first run got passed in next attempts.I think its because of wait problem..cant get correct explicit wait..If I use implicitly it will pass all..I want something explicit kind of wait based on element's appearance as like in appium

Comment: Without seeing the code we can give you 1000 possible reasons that can explain this behaviour. That's why show the code. Then we can give more precise advice.

Comment: public void waitFor(ViewInteraction viewInteraction, ViewAssertion viewAssertion, long timeout) {
        PollingTimeoutIdler idler = new PollingTimeoutIdler(viewInteraction, viewAssertion, timeout);
        IdlingRegistry.getInstance().register(idler);
        viewInteraction.check(viewAssertion);
        IdlingRegistry.getInstance().unregister(idler);
    }

Comment: @mentallurg I am using the above code for explicit wait.But its not working properly I guess.How can I check that

Comment: How do you execute your tests? Where and how you define what is the sequence of the test execution?

Comment: Executing through Spoon task ( SpoonDebugAndroidTest) from terminal. and for order I am using 
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
these annotations. All my tests are independent too

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the animation will help to minimize most flaky fails.

To disable animations from mac terminal

```
adb shell settings put global window_animation_scale 0
adb shell settings put global transition_animation_scale 0
adb shell settings put global animator_duration_scale 0
```

For furthermore give proper sleep time and assertions